# Terraform - Create dynamic kubernetes configmap from module call with for_each expression

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, yaml

So i've got a Terraform module that iterates over YML Files with Team-Names

```
module "team" {
  for_each = { for data in fileset("${path.module}/teams, "*.yaml") : trimsuffix(data, ".yaml") => file("${path.module}/teams/${data}") }
  source   = "git@github.com:extracool-project
  data     = each.value
}
```

This module creates an azuread_group resource and has an output with the azuread team id + name

```
output "team_object_id" { value = azuread_group.extracoolteam.object_id }
```

Now, i want to create a module that takes the outputs and creates ** one ** kubernetes configmap resource that looks similar to this:

```
                                                                                                                                                                         │
│ Data                                                                                                                                                                    │
│ ====                                                                                                                                                                    │
│ coolteams.json:                                                                                                                                                          │
│ ----                                                                                                                                                                    │
│ {                                                                                                                                                                       │
│    "objectid_1":{                                                                                                                                              │
│       "allocationFilters":[                                                                                                                                             │
│          {                                                                                                                                                              │
│             "namespace":"team1",                                                                                                                                            │
│             "cluster":"*"                                                                                                                                               │
│          }                                                                                                                                                              │
│       ]                                                                                                                                                                 │
│    },                                                                                                                                                                   │
│    "objectid_2":{                                                                                                                                              │
│       "allocationFilters":[                                                                                                                                             │
│          {                                                                                                                                                              │
│             "namespace":"team2",                                                                                                                                             │
│             "cluster":"*"                                                                                                                                               │
│          }                                                                                                                                                              │
│       ]                                                                                                                                                                 │
│    }                                                                                                                                                                    │
│ }                                                                                                                                                                       │
│                                                                                                                                                                         │
│                                                                                                                                                                         │
│ BinaryData                                                                                                                                                              │
│ ====                                                                                                                                                                    │
│                                                                                                                                                                         │
│ Events:  <none>
```

i have not been able to find a suitable approach so far
Any help would be apprichiated

THANKS

Comment: Are there any errors? If so, please add them to the question.

Comment: @MarkoE no errors. i simply have not been able to find a similar approach for creating one configmap with module outputs from a foreach call

Comment: What do outputs look like? Can you add that to the question? Without that it's hard to tell how to do what you want.